# Does casting an Object array to a String array use the toString() method of the objects?

Tags: java, arrays, string, object

I need to use the `toString()` method of an object and put it into an array. I'm wondering, If I cast the array to a `String[]`, will it use the `toString()` method?

For Example:

```
public static String[] toStringArray(MyObject[] myObjects) {
    // Will this return the toString() representation of each object?
    return (String[])myObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
public static String[] toStringArray(MyObject[] myObjects) {
    return Stream.of(myObjects)
        .map(MyObject::toString)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: Why use a list at all?

Comment: Because it's easy to write. Less efficient, sure, But simple.

Comment: You misunderstand me. You can just do `return Stream.of(myObjects).map(MyObject::toString).toArray(String[]::new);`. There's no need for the list.

Comment: Yes. That's what I get for doing too many things at once. Shoddy code.

Answer (score 6):

No, it will just fail with a `ClassCastException`.

Casting does not do any conversion on the object instances. It just checks if it has the type that you want to cast it to.

You may want to look at `java.util.Arrays.toString(myObjects)` (gives you a String, though, not a `String[]`).